# What adjust_size in musl libc malloc does?

Tags: c, malloc, libc

I was studying musl libc `malloc` implementation and I am having hard time understanding the `adjust_size` function.

```
static int adjust_size(size_t *n)  
{
    /* Result of pointer difference must fit in ptrdiff_t. */
    if (*n-1 > PTRDIFF_MAX - SIZE_ALIGN - PAGE_SIZE) {
        if (*n) {
            errno = ENOMEM;
            return -1;
        } else {
            *n = SIZE_ALIGN;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    *n = (*n + OVERHEAD + SIZE_ALIGN - 1) & SIZE_MASK;
    return 0;
}
```

For example in the first comparison, why they are not just comparing against `PTRDIFF_MAX`. It is what seems to be the intent from the comment above anyway, and why are they subtracting 1 from `*n`, I think that `(*n-1)` was being compared as unsigned instead of signed, so they are handling the case where `*n` is 0. But I do not know why this is being compared as unsigned in that case as it seems both positions would evaluate to signed numbers at the end.

Also why does they set `*n` to `SIZE_ALIGN` if it is 0? My understanding is that malloc should return `NULL` or a pointer where it can be passed to free without causing an issue if size is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why they are not just comparing against `PTRDIFF_MAX`

Most `malloc` implementation allocate large chunks separately using `mmap`. Because `mmap` allocates memory in pages, `n` needs to be aligned to a page boundary (`PAGE_SIZE`), plus should include chunk header (which is aligned by `SIZE_ALIGN`).

This is why comparison is performed against `PTRDIFF_MAX - SIZE_ALIGN - PAGE_SIZE` instead of `PTRDIFF_MAX` - to make sure all possible future alignment adjustments won't cause chunk size to be greater than `PTRDIFF_MAX`.

> why are they subtracting 1 from `*n`

Because `n` might be aligned later like this:

```
n = (n + SIZE_ALIGN + PAGE_SIZE - 1) & -PAGE_SIZE;
```

And resulting value should be less or equal to `PTRDIFF_MAX`. Value `PTRDIFF_MAX - SIZE_ALIGN - PAGE_SIZE + 1` is still okay, so 1 is subtracted.

> Also why does they set `*n` to `SIZE_ALIGN` if it is 0

Because adjusted chunk size should be greater or equal to `SIZE_ALIGN` bytes to fit `OVERHEAD` bytes of heap overhead plus requested data area should be able to fit 2 pointers used later from `free`. This alignment is assumed later in code.

> I think that `(*n-1)` was being compared as unsigned instead of
>   signed, so they are handling the case where `*n` is 0. But I do not
>   know why this is being compared as unsigned in that case as it seems
>   both positions would evaluate to signed numbers at the end.

I think it could be written simpler (althought this might be incorrect, I am probably need to have a sleep):

```
static int adjust_size(size_t *n)
{
    if (*n > PTRDIFF_MAX - SIZE_ALIGN - PAGE_SIZE + 1) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return -1;
    }
    *n = (*n + OVERHEAD + SIZE_ALIGN - 1) & SIZE_MASK;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. It helped me navigate the code afterwards. The most important point is that there are stuff that are being done that does not make sense until a later part of the code. That was confusing me a lot. For example
They have a later alignment like this: size_t len = n + OVERHEAD + PAGE_SIZE - 1 & -PAGE_SIZE;
which as you suggested. And my assumption of unsigned comparison is correct, what I was missing is that size_t is unsigned.
And your simpler version should work. 0 will be size aligned to SIZE_ALIGN, which is twice as OVERHEAD. so should be fine.